# Solspace Freeform email notifications

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

I'm a relative newbie to Craft CMS / Solspace Freeform. I'm trying to implement a form which will capture some basic details and send to an email address.

I've done the setup correctly (from what I can see) however when I go into email notifications I can only see database entry templates and no email notification templates.

When I test my form it submits the data to the submission page on Craft but no email is ever sent.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

There is a contact form and related template setup by someone prior to me on the website which I know emails to a specified email address, but I can't seem to get mine working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Freeform allows you to [send email notifications 5 different ways](http://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v2/overview/email-notifications.html) (all of them each being able to have their own notification templates, etc).

For setting up [Admin Notifications](http://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v2/overview/email-notifications.html#admin-notifications) specifically, follow these instructions:

> Email notifications can be sent to one or more admin email addresses. To setup:
>
> - In Composer interface for the form, click on the Admin Notifications (envelope icon) tab at the top right.
> - Select and/or add an email template.
> - Specify admin email address(es) in the text area below. Separated multiples by line breaks only.

As for actually choosing between database-based notifications or HTML file-based notifications, setting them up, etc, you can [check out the documentation here](http://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v2/overview/email-notifications.html#overview-of-email-notification-template-options).